# Creating an autocomplete in ASP.NET MVC error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to create an autocomplete textbox in ASP.NET MVC using jquery autocomplete.

This is my Index.cshtml:

```
<div class="autocomplete">
    @Html.TextBox("item", null, new { id = "autocomplete-textbox", @class = "form-control" });
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="autocomplete-button"/>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#autocomplete-textbox').autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete")',
            minlength: 1
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my home controller method:

```
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string item)
    {

        IEnumerable<string> itemsList = new[] { "Ana", "are", "mere", "pere", "papaia", "Aaa", "Ab", "An" };
        IEnumerable<string> filteredResults = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
        {
            filteredResults = itemsList;
        }
        else
        {
            filteredResults = itemsList.Where(s => s.IndexOf(item, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
        }

        return Json(filteredResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My problem is that the parameter item in the JsonResult AutoComplete is always null and so I always get as a JSON response the whole list. What can I do ?

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the jQuery auto complete plugin will send the typed in value with a query string param called `term`, not item(*You can see this if you open up your browsers dev tools-> network tab*) .

So change your server action method parameter name to `term`

```
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string term)
{
  // use term for your checkings
  // to do : Return something    
}
```

Also, i noticed another issue in your code. If the term variable is not empty, you need to set the filtered results (The result of your Where method call) to the  `filteredResults` variable because that it what you are returning.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
{
    filteredResults = itemsList;
}
else
{
    filteredResults = itemsList
             .Where(s => s.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just that you have to name the parameter as "term" that you are using in your controller, as jquery autocomplete widget by default sends the value in a variable named as "term". Therefore just change as below:

public JsonResult AutoComplete(string term)
    {

```
    IEnumerable<string> itemsList = new[] { "Ana", "are", "mere", "pere", "papaia", "Aaa", "Ab", "An" };
    IEnumerable<string> filteredResults = null;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
    {
        filteredResults = itemsList;
    }
    else
    {
        filteredResults = itemsList.Where(s => s.IndexOf(term, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
    }

    return Json(filteredResults, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```